How to recreate the selected list of apps to make a phone call on iOS
Currently, I using the url_launcher package to get the phone call to work
final Uri call = Uri( scheme: 'tel',path: '',);
launchUrl(call);

But in IOS the Uri scheme "tel"
    Make a phone call to <phone number> using the default phone app

Wanted result Preference IOS Contacts 
Are there other workarounds for this
